# Explicit template argument specification

Tags: c++, templates

I started reading about templates and I got confused on the below.

```
template<class T>
T max(T t1, T t2)
{
   if (t1 > t2)
      return t1;
   return t2;
}

int main(){
   std::cout<<max<int>(120,14.55);
   return 0;
}
```

Output is 120. But when I compiled the above I got this warning:

```
warning:passing double for argument 2 to T max(T, T) [with T = int].
```

My question is why this warning came, since I have already instantiated for `T max(int t1,double t2)`.

Because as per my understanding here if I explicitly mention only one data type (here `int`), other would be deducted from the argument type (`14.55`) by the compiler. That means `T max(T t1, T t2)` instantiates `T max(int t1,double t2)` in this case. I read this concept from some template documents on Internet.

Please clear my doubts else I can't proceed further.

Comment: You need to read more about templates. The `T` in `template<class T>` is the type used for _both_ arguments, and you explicitly set that to `int` in the call.

Comment: Yes Joachim.even that was my understanding but i read the above concept from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257589/An-Idiots-Guide-to-Cplusplus-Templates-Part-1.     Could you pls atleast tell me ,what i understood is wrong or not?

Answer (score 2):

Your particular template only has one template parameter, `T`. Which means that `max<int>` creates this:

```
int max(int t1, int t2)
```

There is no way to generate `max(int, double)` out of this template. If you want mixed-type arguments, the template would have to look like this:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
/*some return type*/ max(T1 t1, T2 t2)
```

However, now it's not easy to determine what the return type should be, and `type_traits` would probably be needed to derive a correct return type for such a function.

Comment: For the return type, see [`std::common_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type).

Answer (score 1):

```
std::cout << max<int>(120,14.55);
```

This line is equavivalent to using of function
int max(int, int), so compiler gives warning for conversion from 14.55 to 14 - possible loss of data.

If you want to compare diffrent types of data, you should use

```
template<class T, class T1, class T2>
T max(T1 t1, T2 t2)
{
   if (t1 > t2)
      return T(t1);
   return T(t2);
}
```

later in main.cpp:

```
float a = max<float, int, double>(10, 11.0);
```

but it's not the best way to do it.

Comment: If that is the case then if i try with max<int,int>(120,14.55);   again i should get only warning. but i got compile time error .Below is the error>                                                     error:  no matching function for call to max(int, double).

Answer (score 0):

> why this warning came is my question since i have already instantiated for `T max(int t1,double t2)`.

No you haven't. Providing `int` as the template parameter instantiates the template by replacing all occurences of the parameter with `int`:

```
T max(T t1, T t2)    becomes    int max(int t1, int t2)
```

> Because as per my understanding here if i explicitly mention only one data type (here int), other would be deducted from the argument type

No. Your template has only one parameter, used for both function argument types; so if you specify that parameter, then it's used for both (and the return type as well). If you want these to be parametrised separately, then you'll need a separate parameter for each.

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
???? max(T1 t1, T2 t2)
```

How best to specify the return type is left as an exercise.

Now, if you only provide the first argument, the second is deduced from the second function argument:

```
max<int>(120,14.55);  // T1=int given, T2=double deduced -> max(int,double)
max(120,14.55)        // T1=int, T2=double both deduced  -> max(int,double)
```

Comment: Mike thanks for your quick reply                                        My doubt is exactly on this part what you have mentioned                            max<int>(120,14.55);  // "int" given, "double" deduced -> That means  T max(T t1, T t2)    should become   int max(int t1, double t2) .Then why we are deducing double??

Comment: Could you pls make this clear?What you have said is my exact doubt?

Comment: @SubiSuresh: Your template only has one parameter, `T`. If you specify that it should be `int`, then it will be `int` *everywhere* - in particular, the function declaration will be `int max(int,int)`. My example template has two parameters, `T1` and `T2`, which can be specified separately; specifying the first does not specify the second, leaving it free to be deduced.

Comment: .Ok mike i understood .One more last query.It will be of great help if you can comment.                                                If that is the concept then when i compiled for below template <typename T>max<int,int>(120,14.55);                                  why i got error  error: no matching function for call to âmax(int, double) .

Comment: @SubiSuresh: Without seeing exactly what template you're instantiating, and exactly how you're instantiating it, I can't say exactly why you get that error. You should ask that as a separate question, or clarify this question, if the answers here don't cover it.

Comment: template<class T>
    T max(T t1, T t2)
{
   if (t1 > t2)
      return t1;
   return t2;
}

int main(){
   std::cout<<max<int,int>(120,14.55);
   return 0;
}

Comment: >After compilation of the above i got  error: no matching function for call to 'max(int, double)'.since  i have instantiated with int how come the error can come like no matching function for max(int,double).Pls comment and clarify my doubt.i know that since only 1 template parametre is there max<int,int>doesnt make any sense.but still how this type of error can occur

Comment: @SubiSuresh: The template only has one parameter, so you can't provide two. I don't know why you get that particular error, but `max<int,int>` is ill-formed and should certainly give some kind of error.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike for even clarifying my small doubts.